# How to open password change dialog from gnome-control-center from the terminal?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, password, gnome-shell, gui

I can open the User sections by running `gnome-control-center` but I need to access directly the password dialog box. Is there a way to directly open it?

[image]

Comment: can this not be done by just typing `passwd` in the terminal? [reference](https://thishosting.rocks/change-password-linux-terminal/)

Comment: It surely can but I need to show graphical dialog hence the requirement.

Comment: Make your own: `echo -e $(zenity --forms --title="Change Password" --text="Password for $USER" --separator="\n" --add-password="Old Password" --add-password="New Password" --add-password="Confirm New Password") | passwd`

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to directly open this dialog using a terminal command. You can, however, directly open the "Users" panel in Settings with the command

```
gnome-control-center user-accounts
```

from where a single click opens the dialog.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of `user-accounts` panel but I have an application which runs in Kiosk mode so we don't want the user to access other settings. Is it possible to directly open the password dialog?

Comment: See my answer, which is only my take on it.

Comment: @vanadium is right - `gnome-control-center -l` gives you a list of all directly accessible panels. As best as I can tell password change is not part of this.

Comment: `gnome-control-center user-accounts --gtk-debug=all` lets you debug the "Users" panel, but I'm not sure if it let's you find a direct link entry...

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own GUI dialog in a bash script like so:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while true
    do
    input=$(zenity --forms --title="Change Password" --text="Password for $USER" --separator="\n" --add-password="Old Password" --add-password="New Password" --add-password="Confirm New Password")
    [[ "$?" != "0" ]] && break
    echo -e "$input" | passwd && zenity --info  --text="Password for $USER successfuly changed." --no-wrap && break || \
    zenity --forms --title="Change Password Error" --text="Please Enter Valid Password for $USER"
    [[ "$?" != "0" ]] && break
    done
```

You will need to install [`zenity`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man1/zenity.1.html) if it is not already installed like so:

```
sudo apt install zenity
```